# TypeORM OneToMany relation to multiple fields

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

How to make something like this [scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpwml.png) in **TypeORM**?

Entity Child:

```js
@Field(() => Parent, { nullable: true })
@ManyToOne(() => Parent, (parent) => parent.children)
father: Parent;

@Field(() => Parent, { nullable: true })
@ManyToOne(() => Parent, (parent) => parent.children)
mother: Parent;
```

Entity Parent:

```js
@OneToMany(() => Child, 'mother') // missing father
children: Child[];
```

My problem is how to make *OneToMany* relation to `mother` AND `father` on entity Parent.